# Continuity in product topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sequentially compact Hausdorff topological spaces and let $f:X\times Y\to \mathbb{C}.$ Equip $X\times Y$ with the product topology.

Is sequential criteria for continuity valid in this scenario? In other words,

If for every sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ in $X\times Y$ with $x_n\to x_0$ and $y_n\to y_0$, $f(x_n,y_n)\to f(x_0,y_0)$, can we conclude that $f$ is continuous?

Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. We always have the sequence $(x_n, y_n) \to (x,y)$ if and only if $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$.

**Lemma** Let $f: X \to Y$. If the function $f$ is continous, then for every convergent sequence $x_n \to x$, the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$.

So your question basically asks whether or not the converse of the lemma above is true. But the converse only holds if $X$ is first-countable.